# Product of two columsn, added to the next row, and so forth

Tags: awk, pipe, multiple-columns

I am attempting to produce the product each row in a multi-row file and add it the subsequent row and so fort.

So I would essentially go with

```
awk '{print $1 "/t" ($2 * $3)' filename > temp
```

how would this be looped for each unique id in column 1? sample data below.

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
name1   14   10
name1   48   10
name2   23   98
name3   90   28
name4   83   6
name4   5    3
name3   15   7
```

Comment: Thank you for showing your effort in order to fix your problem, please do always add expected output too in your posts.

Comment: Apologies for not making it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading it correctly you need to have the multiplication of 2nd and 3rd column in each row and then add them to same 1st column values if this is the case then following may help you here.

```
awk '{a[$1]=(a[$1]?a[$1]+($2 * $3):$2*$3)} END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]}}' Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** You could use `sort` and `awk` in case you need output in sorted order.

```
sort -k1 Input_file |
awk '
prev!=$1 && prev{
  print prev,total
  total=prev=""
}
{
  total+=($2*$3)
  prev=$1
}
END{
  if(prev && total){
    print prev,total
  }
}'
```

***Solution 3rd:*** In case you need to have the same order of output as like Input_file's first field then following may help.

```
awk '
!a[$1]++{
  b[++count]=$1
}
{
  c[$1]=(c[$1]?c[$1] + ($2*$3):($2*$3))
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print b[i],c[b[i]]
  }
}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
name1 620
name2 2254
name3 2625
name4 513
```

Comment: @serious, no need to apology we are all here for learning, keep learning and keep sharing knowledge on this great site SO.